# AJAX and form validation using AJAX

Tags: ajax

I have been trying to submit a form using ajax. I can already read the errors when there is one but I can't get the message when there is no error. Please find below my php code and then the jquery codes as follows.

**script side code**

```
    $error=[];

    $message=[];

    $name=isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:"";

    $email=isset($_POST["email"])?$database->cleaner($_POST["email"]):"";

    $message=isset($_POST["message"])?$_POST["message"]:"";

    if(empty($name)){
        $error[]="Name required";    
    }


    if(empty($email)){
        $error[]="Email required";    
    }


    if(empty($message)){
        $error[]="Message required";    
    }
    // sending back the errors 

    if(!empty($error)){
        $errors=array("error"=>$error);
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }


     /*returning processed data with a thank you message.*/

    if(($name) && ($email)&& ($message)){
        $query="insert into contact_messages(name,email,message)values('$name' ,'$email','$message')";

        $result=$database->query($query); 

        if($result){

            $message[]="thank you";

            $m=array("message"=>$message);

            echo json_encode($m);
        }
    }
```

**javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
       $('form').submit(function (event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var formDetails=$(this).serialize();
           $.post('page.php',formDetails,function(data){
              var json=$.parseJSON(data);
              if(json.error){
                 for(key in json){
                     var output=$("#man").css('display','block').append('<p>' + json[key]  +   '</p>');
                 }
              }
              else if(json.message){
                 for(key in json){
                     var output=$("#man").css('display','block').append('<p>' + json[key]  +   '</p>');
                 }
              } 
           });                
      }); 
    });
```

Comment: Data inserted successfully?

Comment: Lots of questions out there in stack overflow like this. Please search before ask

Comment: like i mentioned i can only read out the errors sent back to me from the script